# Item is not selected form drop down list(Angular Js)

Tags: angular, bootstrap-4

I choose a item from category drop down list and want to save as a object in console from template driven form.

But I got category is undefined.

Here is my Form-template code:-

```html
<form #f="ngForm" (ngSubmit)="save(f.value)">
        <div class="form-group">
          <label for="title">Title</label>
          <input ngModel name="title" id="title" type="text" class="form-control" >
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
          <label for="price">Price</label>
          <div class="input-group">
            <span class="input-group-append">$</span>
            <input ngModel name="price" id="price" type="number" class="form-control">
          </div>
        </div>
                   
        **<div class="form-group">
          <label for="category">Category</label>
          <select ngModel name="category" id="category" type="text" class="form-control">
            <option value=""></option>
            <option *ngFor="let c of categories$ | async" [value]="c.$key">
              {{ c.name }}
            </option>
          </select>
        </div>**  

        <div class="form-group">
          <label for="imageUrl">Image URL</label>
          <input ngModel name="imageUrl" id="imageUrl" type="text" class="form-control" >
        </div>        
        <button class="btn btn-primary">Save</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger">Delete</button>
    </form>
```

[Screen Shoot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ukYgK.png)

Could you please guide me why Category is "Undefined"

Firebase database :-
[Firebase database category](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0L3a3.png)

Comment: Are you getting `c.$key` values, have you looked at it, and one more thing try giving your button `type="submit"` to be more precise

Comment: Hello, Thank you for your help...when I remove [value]="c.$key" ...now it is working.Now I am confuse.This  [value]="c.$key" is used for binding purpose and my category list is comming from firebase database.

Comment: Hello, Thank you for your help...when I remove [value]="c.$key" ...now it is working.Now I am confuse.This  [value]="c.$key" is used for binding purpose and my category list is comming from firebase database.So, could please you help what is happening here.I have updated category list form firbase view in my question.

Comment: If you are getting the correct value or either getting the value then try to use `[value]="c['$key']"`

Comment: I have tried with this...but still I get undefined... <option *ngFor="let c of categories$ | async" [value]="c['$key']" >